# Regular expression to get value with duplicate data

Tags: regex

Hi trying to extract my required string from given string. Given string looks like below.

> 1|a1|id11-name11,x|a2|id21-name21,y|a3|id31-name31~id32-name32,y4|a4|id41-name41~id42-name42~id43-name43

Expected output:

> a1~name11|a2~name21|a3~name31|a3~name32|a4~name41|a4~name42|a4~name43

Regular Expression:

```
(^|,)[^|]{0,}\|([^|]{0,})\|(~){0,}[^-]{0,}-([^,~]{0,})
```

Extracting $2~$4| or \2~\4|

Regular Expression output:

> a1~name11|a2~name21|a3~name31|

Is it possible to get `a3~name32` along with `a3~name31` using regular expression? Using multiple regular expression is also fine. Values in the third part after pipe symbol is not limited to 4 different values(`id41-name41~id42-name42~id43-name43`). This could be like `id41-name41~id42-name42~id43-name43~id43-name43~id43-name43~id43-name43...`

Comment: Is the number of term limited to 4 (or is it unbounded)

Comment: @Bohemian It is not limited to 4 but, it is limited to some fixed value

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices first one is to **split the string** into many parts and get what you want. 
Second one depends on the longest repeated part. In your case it is `idxx-namexx`.
If it is limited to a **reasonable** **value** you can repeat that part in you regex so you get all the parts. For instance for 2 you need to add the second part as follows:

```
([a-zA-Z]\d)\|(id\d+-(name\d+))(~?id\d+-(name\d+))?
______________-------1-------- _---------2--------_________
```

The groups will be 
\1~\3 and 
\1~\5

You can check it in [Regex101 Site](https://regex101.com/r/pR3xJ3/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But values of `id31-name31~id32-name32` are not limited to two values, it could be `id31-name31~id32-name32~id32-name32~id32-name32`. Could there be any other solution?

Comment: is it limited to 4 ? the problem with repeated grouping it catch only the last matched group that's why if you want to catch them all you need to repeat the second group as many times.

Comment: Nope. It's not even limited to 4. There can be any number of repetitions.